# regex issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"foo = '@test.bar';\nfooa = @test.darn;".match(/@([a-z][a-z\.-_]*)/igm)
```

Why does this match

```
["@test.bar", "@test.darn;"]
```

rather than just

```
["@test.bar", "@test.darn"]
```

?

Comment: I guess the range from `.` to `_` includes `;` but not `'`

Comment: Did you want to include the "-" character or you really wanted to specify a range ?

Comment: @elclanrs `\w` also includes `\d`

Comment: Funnily enough, the `\ ` is actually included in that range as well, so the `\ ` in the OP's question is doubly redundant.

Comment: @inhan: Oh, yeah you're right...I think OP want's `-` as well, so it wasn't a range anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), some letters have special meanings. The dot for example has none and does not need to be escaped. The minus in contrast defines a range of characters, and if you mean literally minus you need to escape it or put it in the end/beginning of the character class. Your range from `.` to `_` actually includes `./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`. You may want to use `[a-z.\-_]` or `[a-z._-]` instead.

Comment: oh. I always thought dot had to be escaped while minus hadn't, nice catch.

Comment: @Nico: Typically no character that has special meaning outside `[]` has to be escaped inside. The `-` needs to be escaped because it has special meaning inside `[]`.

Comment: @elclanrs Not true. You need to escape the closing square bracket as well - not to mention the back slash nd the caret of course.

Comment: @elclanrs `^` has to be escaped inside a character class  as well.

Comment: @inhan & @JanDvorak: Well, yeah.. `^` has special meaning inside `[]` so it has to be escaped, and `]` well I think that one seems pretty obvious...

Comment: To be escaped inside a character class: `^-]\ `